# How to fit navbar to page

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get the navbar in this html to fit the page but I just can't seem to get it do that. It's within a container and then within another div so I suspect that might be the problem but I simply cannot get this to work and it would be a big help if I knew how to fix things like this in the future.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
        <title>Zurvo - Collaborative Research</title>
    <body>
<!-- BEGIN: Sticky Header -->
<div id="header_container">
    <div id="header">
        Header Content
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END: Sticky Header -->
<!-- BEGIN: Page Content -->    
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
    <ul id="list-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- END: Page Content -->




    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* BEGIN: Header Style */
/* Reset body padding and margins */
body { margin:0; padding:0; background-color:
#F5F1DE; }

/* Make Header Sticky */
#header_container { background-color:#4682B4; border:1px solid #666; height:60px; left:0; position:fixed; width:100%; top:0; border-bottom: 2px solid #ced7df; }
#header{ line-height:60px; margin:0 auto; width:940px; text-align:center; }

/* CSS for the content of page. I am giving top and bottom padding of 80px to make sure the header and footer do not overlap the content.*/
#container { margin:0 auto; overflow:auto; padding:80px 0; width:940px; }
#content{}
/* Format Positions Of The Login Form */
.login {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 310px;
}
.container {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 640px;
}
.login p.submit {
  text-align: right;
}

.login-help {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: 3399FF;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #2a85a1;
}

.login-help a {
  color: #3399FF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.login-help a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #c9c9c9 !important;
  font-size: 13px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 13px;
}
/* Design The Box */
.container {
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 640px;
}
.login:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: steelblue;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.login h1 {
  margin: -20px -20px 21px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0 1px whitesmoke;
}

.login p {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}

.login p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.login input[type=text], .login input[type=password] {
  width: 278px;
}

.login p.remember_me {
  float: left;
  line-height: 31px;
}

.login p.remember_me label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.login p.remember_me input {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Set The Navbar For Homepage Styling */
#content {min-height:1000px;width:300px;}

ul#list-nav {
    position:relative;
    bottom:39px;
  margin:20px;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  width:800px;
}
ul#list-nav li {
  display:inline
}
ul#list-nav li a {
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:5px 0;
 width:100px;
 background:#485e49;
 color:#eee;
 float:left;
}
ul#list-nav li a {
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid #fff;
}
ul#list-nav li a:hover {
  background:#a2b3a1;
  color:#000
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific as to what do you mean by "fit the page" ? you mean, fit navbar width to page width?

Comment: Yes! That's what I meant. I'm pretty new to html/css so I forget to use proper terms.

Answer (score 0):

Total width of list-nav is 840px space available (.container) is 640px. It can not fit.

Try

```
ul#list-nav {
  position:relative;
  bottom:39px;
  margin:20px;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  /* replace this line width:800px; */
  width:600px; /* plus margin left 20px, margin right 20px ... 640px */
}
```

Nobody can duplicate because page is incomplete. I assumed you removed the closing tags to compress the question, but it also means everybody must assume what does not fit means.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fixed css, the changes i've made:

```
#container {
    width:100%;
}

#content {
    width:100%;
}

ul#list-nav {
    margin-top:20px;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
}

ul#list-nav li {
    width:100%
}

ul#list-nav li a {
    width:100%;
}
```

**And here is the full fixed code**

```css
/* BEGIN: Header Style */

/* Reset body padding and margins */
 body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #F5F1DE;
}
/* Make Header Sticky */
 #header_container {
    background-color:#4682B4;
    border:1px solid #666;
    height:60px;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ced7df;
}
#header {
    line-height:60px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:940px;
    text-align:center;
}
/* CSS for the content of page. I am giving top and bottom padding of 80px to make sure the header and footer do not overlap the content.*/
 #container {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:80px 0;
    width:100%;
}

/* Format Positions Of The Login Form */
 .login {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px;
    width: 310px;
}
.login p.submit {
    text-align: right;
}
.login-help {
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: 3399FF;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #2a85a1;
}
.login-help a {
    color: #3399FF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.login-help a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #c9c9c9 !important;
    font-size: 13px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/* Design The Box */
 .container {
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 640px;
}
.login:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    right: -8px;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: steelblue;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.login h1 {
    margin: -20px -20px 21px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px white;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, whiteffd, #eef2f5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px whitesmoke;
    box-shadow: 0 1px whitesmoke;
}
.login p {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}
.login p:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.login input[type=text], .login input[type=password] {
    width: 278px;
}
.login p.remember_me {
    float: left;
    line-height: 31px;
}
.login p.remember_me label {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.login p.remember_me input {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Set The Navbar For Homepage Styling */
 #content {
    min-height:1000px;
    width:100%;
}
ul#list-nav {
    position:relative;
    bottom:39px;
    margin-top:20px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
}
ul#list-nav li {
    width:100%
}
ul#list-nav li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 0;
    width:100%;
    background:#485e49;
    color:#eee;
    float:left;
}
ul#list-nav li a {
    text-align:center;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    display:inline-block;
}
ul#list-nav li a:hover {
    background:#a2b3a1;
    color:#000
}
```

```html
<!-- BEGIN: Sticky Header -->
<div id="header_container">
    <div id="header">Header Content</div>
</div>
<!-- END: Sticky Header -->
<!-- BEGIN: Page Content -->
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <ul id="list-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END: Page Content -->
```